# Xamarin.Forms and XamarinMediaManager: how to manage errors cases?

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin.forms, audio-streaming, plugin.mediamanager.forms

I use the **XamarinMediaManager** in a **Xamarin.Forms** project, to play audio from a web radio.

But I would like to manage error cases, like when the URL is no longer available, or if there is not internet access for example.

I launch the audio stream like this:

`var mediaItem = await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(audioUrl);`

If I use a "wrong" URL, nothing happens, but I didn't found how to "identify" this case. It's the same thing if I activate the airplane mode.

I would like to display an error message to the user in both cases, so he could understand why the audio doesn't launch.

***Is there a way to manage this?***

Comment: https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#hook-into-events

Comment: Good idea @Jason. I've tried but the `MediaItemFailed`event is not fired if I use a wrong URL or the airplane mode. I already use the `StateChanged`event that is well fired: but the state passed to "Pause" if I use a wrong URL or the airplane mode. So it's not possible to track an error like I would like to.

Comment: @Gold.strike About internet available, you can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android) to check.

Comment: Hi @CherryBu-MSFT you're right for this specific case. One also suggested me another solution for other cases by checking `MediaItem.Title`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've implemented a solution that one have suggested by using `MediaItem.Title`:

```
var mediaItem = await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(radioUrl);
var currentTitle = mediaItem.Title;
```

This only works for **iOS**, on **Android** the use of `mediaItem.Title` raise an Exception...

So, to manage **Android** case, I use the `MediaItemFailed`:

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaItemFailed += OnCurrentMediaItemFailed;
```

The event is only **raised after 1 minute** on **Android**, and it's **not raised at all on iOS**.

This solution is not perfect and is no the same for 2 platforms, but I don't found a better one yet...